# how to make the minute variable in automation anywhere show two digits when minutes is less than 10

Tags: variables, timestamp, rpa, automationanywhere, minute

In Automation Anywhere, the minute system variable ($Minute$) will only return 1 digit if minutes is less than 10. The variable manager doesn't allow for the format to be edited.

Can you please suggest any workarounds? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a variable and name it $vMinute$.
- Using if condition check if the day is less than 10, then add 0 to the left using variable operation.

The same approach can be done for the hour variable as well.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Gabor if any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.